# JSonMapping exection when a Spring Rest service is invoked

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc project and am trying to test out a rest services I generated the DAO and Domain objects through MyEclipse. I am attempting to call a service and get the following error. There are instructions within that error, but frankly don't know where to start with regards to this. In the error message campus and metroarea is referenced And there is a one to one relationship Thanks

`org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->.Campus["metroarea"]->Metroarea_$$_javassist_9["hibernateLazyInitializer"])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have helped if I had the latest version of Jackson in my maven build. That fixed the issue.